# Monthly-hourly-average calculate from Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have the time and the values in the data base. I need to calculate for a given month the average during each hour i.e.

```
YYYY-mm-dd (the day can be omitted)
2021-01-01 00:00:00 value=avg(values from 00:00:00 until 00:59:59 for every day of this month at this hour interval) 
2021-01-01 01:00:00 value=avg(values from 01:00:00 until 01:59:59 idem as above)
...
2021-01-01 23:00:00 value=avg(values from 23:00:00 until 23:59:59)
2021-02-01 00:00:00 value=avg(values from 00:00:00 until 00:59:59)
2021-02-01 01:00:00 value=avg(values from 01:00:00 until 01:59:59)
...
2021-02-01 23:00:00 value=avg(values from 23:00:00 until 23:59:59)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [`date_trunc('hour', datestamp)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) in a GROUP BY statement, something like this.

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', datestamp) hour_beginning, AVG(value) average_value
  FROM mytable
 WHERE datestamp >= '2021-01-01'
   AND datestamp <  '2021-02-01'
 GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', datestamp)
 ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', datestamp)
```

To generalize, in place of `DATE_TRUNC` you can use any injective function.

You could use

```
to_char(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-01 HH24:00:00')
```

to get one result row per hour for every month in your date range.

```
SELECT to_char(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-01 HH24:00:00') hour, 
       AVG(value) average_value
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY to_char(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-01 HH24:00:00')
 ORDER BY to_char(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-01 HH24:00:00')
```

Comment: this will give the daily-hourly average values; you can see that after 2021-01 23:00 we have the next month starting; I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: The second part works after the edit: that is
`SELECT to_char(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-01 HH24:00:00') as hour, count(values) FROM table_name  GROUP BY to_char(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-01 HH24:00:00') ORDER BY to_char(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-01 HH24:00:00')` here I used the count to verify that the values are correct. This is the answer; the DATE_TRUNC version (I played a lot with it) does give the daily-average.